# Is it possible to alter the playback *preview* speed?

Tags: premiere, playback

Is it possible to change the speed of Premiere's playback of the video without altering the speed of the produced version? Even if I could play it only 1.5x faster, it would mean a lot of time saved in the long run.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes - while playing the video, press the `L` key to increase playback speed and press the `J` key to decrease it.

For further options, please reference the relevant [Premiere Pro documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/premierepro/cs/using/WS52A45F55-4237-480c-86F0-9A3869DBEF57.html).

Comment: Actually if you press J one time from 100% speed, it will pause (0% speed) then it plays backwards.

Comment: @AdamanthysBixler-Zavalla Try Shift + J and Shift + L to decrease/increase speed 10% at a time

Comment: How do I reset back to 100% playback rate?

Comment: Nevermind, just hit space to pause and resure and it will reset playback rate

Answer (score 6):

The K key is a modifier and stop playback key.

Play in reverse

To move the playhead in reverse at a normal speed, press J.

To move it backwards faster, press JJ.

To move backward slowly, press J and K.

To move back one frame at a time, press K and tap the J key.

To play in reverse slightly faster, press Shift + J.

.
.

Play forward

To move the playhead forward, press L.

To move it forward faster, press LL.

To move forward slowly, press L and K.

To move forward one frame at a time, press K and tap the L key.

To play forward slightly faster, press Shift + L.